# Writing or Reading reading to specific records of an NFC tag?

Tags: android, security, nfc, payload, ndef

I'm aware that an NDEF message on an NFC tag is made up of a number of records that each contain a payload which makes up the message stored on the tag.

Is it possible to read or write to a specific record?

I'm asking because I want to know if it would be possible to store, for example, a unique ID in a one record, and have other data stored in the other records. This way, when reading from the tag, I could read only that record to return the unique ID.

Possible?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading or writing is always done with the whole NDEF message. This NDEF message can contain several NDEF records. You can hande the individual records in your code separately, such as getting the data, the type etc., but the comunication to the tag is always based on the whole NDEF message.